# Is "collide" natural here?

Tags: word-choice

What made him drive off the road? Did he **collide** with another car?

Is **collide** natural here? And would it mean that he hit the other car?

Comment: It is grammatical and natural but not very likely. If a collision made one car leave the road there would almost certainly be another damaged car at the scene. It would be more likely that the driver "swerved to avoid another car" or "misjudged a bend" or "skidded on ice" or "had a burst tyre."

Answer (score 1):

`Collide` is reasonably natural in this context, and certainly means that there was contact.

The use of `hit the other car` versus `was hit by the other car` is an open question. I would say that `collide with` very slightly insinuates that the main driver is considered at fault, whereas most usages of `hit` very strongly lay the blame in one direction of the other. Whether that matters to you is not clear from the question as it stands.